# How to compare two columns, using python?

Tags: python, database, uitableview, pandas, ipython

I want to compare two continuous home price Sale, and create new column that stores binary variables.

This is my process so far:

```
dataset['High'] = dataset['November'].map(lambda x: 1 if x>50000 else 0)
```

This allows me to work on only one column, but I want to compare both **November** and **December** home price columns and create new column that contains binary variables.

I want this **output**

```
November -  December -  NewCol
-------------------------------
651200   -   626600  -    0
420900   -   423600  -    1
82300    -   83100   -    1
177000   -   169600  -    0
285500   -   206300  -    0
633900   -   640000  -    1
218900   -   222400  -    1
461700   -   403800  -    0
419100   -   421300  -    1
127600   -   128300  -    1
553400   -   547800  -    0
```

November and December is a continuous variable, and so I wanted by converting it to a binary variable.  I want to use the ifelse() function to create a variable, called **"NewCol"**, which takes on a value of **"1"** if the **['November']** column is greater than **['December']**, and takes on a value of **"0"** otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @3novak but with casting. One uses `pandas` for greater efficiency but when you use something like `map` that needs values expressed as (more expensive) python variables, you may as well just use python lists. Try to use pandas operations that apply to entire series and dataframes instead.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> df
    November  December
0     651200    626600
1     420900    423600
2      82300     83100
3     177000    169600
4     285500    206300
5     633900    640000
6     218900    222400
7     461700    403800
8     419100    421300
9     127600    128300
10    553400    547800
>>> df['Higher'] = df['December'].gt(df['November']).astype(int)
>>> df
    November  December  Higher
0     651200    626600       0
1     420900    423600       1
2      82300     83100       1
3     177000    169600       0
4     285500    206300       0
5     633900    640000       1
6     218900    222400       1
7     461700    403800       0
8     419100    421300       1
9     127600    128300       1
10    553400    547800       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer: This would do the trick.

```
dataset['deff'] = np.where(dataset['2016-11'] >= dataset['2016-12'], 0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use the following to create a boolean column. We don't even need to use an `ifelse` statement. Instead we can use the vectorized nature of pandas data frames.

```
data['NewCol'] = data['November'] > data['December']
```

This returns a column of `True` and `False` values instead of `1` and `0`, but they are functionally equivalent. You can sum, take means, etc. treating `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`.

Comment: Thank you, but I can the solution.

Comment: @user3393879 you can the solution? That's great! ... is it?

Comment: You can also use `data['NewCol'] = (data['November'] > data['December']).astype(int)`. It returns a column of `1` and `0`